# Algorithmic riddle: sequence with random access, insertion and remotion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Describe a data structure where:

- **Any item is indexed by an integral value like in an array**

  - an integer can index a single value
  - integers used to index items are *contiguous*: they go from 1 to `n` without holes
- **Getting the item at position `i` (ie: the item associated to the integer `i`) should be as fast as possible**

  - random access
- **Inserting a new item at position `i` should be as fast as possible**

  - this will right-shift any item from `i` onwards
- **Removing an item at position `i` should also be as fast as possible**

  - this will left-shift any item from `i+1` onwards

EDIT: a little thing I forgot about: item indices can only be shifted when adding/removing one, they cannot be randomly swapped.

In this description `n` is the size of the structure (ie: how many items it contains), and `i` is a generic integer (1 <= `i` <= `n`), of course.

---

I heard this from a guy I met in my faculty. Don't know if it's an interview question, an exam question, just a riddle or what, but I guess it could be everything.

If I recall correctly (but hey, it was before December 24th) he said such a data structure could be implemented either with `O(sqrt n)` insertion/remotion and `O(1)` access time, or with `O(log n)` for any operation.

---

EDIT: Some right answers have been given. Read it if you don't want to think any more about this problem.

Comment: In these days I found a solution, should I add it to the question, or via an answer?

Comment: Add as an answer - but I would wait a day or so to let people have fun answering it ;-)

Comment: I don't understand. If you had your problem solved ... why did you post a question?

Comment: I found this question interesting, and since it smelled like a possible interview-question I wanted to share it with SO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, any kind of self-balancing binary tree (e.g., red-black) will provide all three operations for `O(logn)`. C++ map **RB** mentioned is one example (if I didn't forget C++ completely).

As for the indexing (`get` operation), there's a standard trick. We'll store in each node how many nodes its left subtree has. Now we can locate element at position `i` in `O(logn)` time in a manner like this

```
Data get(Node root, int i) {
    if (i <= root.leftCount) {
        return get(root.left, i);
    } else if (i == root.leftCount + 1) {
        return node;
    } else {
        return get(root.right, i - root.leftCount - 1);
    }
}
```

Obviously, each time element is added or removed, `leftCount` values will have to be recomputed, but that'll need to be done only for `O(logn)` nodes. (think how many nodes include removed one in their left subtree - only the ones directly between it and root)

Comment: Awww, I feel shamed: it took me a week (well, thinking about this only on some random spare time) to find this solution!

Comment: That would be the dynamic order statistic, wouldn't it? This will give you the i'th *smallest* (or largest, depending on your ordering) element.

Comment: @peoro No need to: I was avare of the basic approach before. Anyway, I hope to crack `sqrt n` method reasonably soon :)

Comment: @axw Sorry, I have no idea what dynamic order statistic is :)

Comment: I gave up about the `O(sqrt n)` algorithm. :(

Comment: @Nikita: Sorry, I've been reading Introduction to Algorithms recently ;) The i'th order statistic of a set {1,2,...,n-1,n} is the element with the i'th smallest key. So using this assumes that the values of the data structure are ordered. I expect that's a counter question you're meant to ask in the interview.

Comment: @axw That's a good thing nobody asked me such question, then :)

Answer (score 2):

A skip list can do insertion/removal/index lookup each in `O(log n)`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist

For the `O(n^1/2)` insert/remove and `O(1)` index, I assume something a bit like a C++ `deque`, but consisting of `n^1/2` contiguous blocks, each of `n^1/2` elements (+/-1 on each square root, of course). To remove, you have to shuffle down part of the block containing the removed element (`O(n^1/2)`), and then shuffle down the *whole* of the higher blocks, which you'd do by adjusting an offset for each block (at most `O(n^1/2)` blocks) rather than actually moving anything. To insert, you may have to reallocate a block (`O(n^1/2)`) and adjust offsets. In both cases, you may also have to shift one or two elements off the start/end of some blocks to the end/start of the previous/next block, again at most `O(n^1/2)` times, to maintain an invariant that no two blocks differ in size by more than 1, except for the last which is used to take up slack. Finally, you sometimes have to create or destroy a block. Lookup is `O(1)` because you can get to within one block of the element you're looking for with a single division, then consult the stored offsets for one or two blocks to actually find it.

Don't know what that's called, though, or whether I've missed some important detail that means it doesn't work as I've described it.

Comment: Woah, nice! it looks really interesting. It's a rather complicated solution, I'll try to understand it and see if I can spot any problem. Didn't know of Skip Lists.

Comment: It's a promising idea, but you seem to contradict yourself. On one hand, you require sizes of all blocks to differ no more than by one. On the other, you propose to create empty blocks and destroy them.

Comment: @peoro: I'm a bit worried about whether insertion/removal really does require only an O(1) operation to each block. My intuition is that you just have to move 1 or 2 elements across each boundary to keep it all balanced, and reallocate at most one block each time. But I haven't worked it all out, I just have a picture in mind.

Comment: @Nikita: "except for the last". I'm not sure exactly what happens with the block at the end. The plan, though, is to create it empty, and then as insertions are performed try to move extra elements up into it (1 at a time), so that by the time another one has to be created, the previous one is balanced. Basically, each insertion/removal gives us permission to apply an O(1) operation to each block, plus operations to O(1) blocks that are linear in the size of the block. I think this is enough reallocation and shifting, provided we over-allocate some unused space at each end of each block.

Comment: @Steve I see. But I don't get the whole concept of shifting one element from end of one block to the start of the next. If we have `[12345][abcde]`, moving `5` to a second block would require moving `abcd` to the right and then pushing `e` to the third block and so on. Shifting is `O(sqrt n)` operation on one block and thus we can shift only `O(1)` blocks. In this case, we could leave second block with six elements, but what if it already has six elements? (we can't make it 7 - difference can't be more than 1)

Comment: @Nikita: hence the over-allocation: `[..12345..][..abcde..]` -> `[..1234...][.5abcd...][....e....]`, sort of thing, and each row records how much slack space there is at the start. And then when we do it again and that middle row is running up against the LHS, we can shift the whole row right within its buffer, provided that we only have to shift at most a constant number of rows for each insert/remove. Which tells us how much slack space is needed - with k rows, each of which can "creep" 1 per op, we'd need slack in each row proportional to k, which is `n^1/2`, so linear over-allocation.

Comment: @Nikita: if this (or something similar) turns out to be a published structure, then it may actually be *simpler* than I've said, because someone will have come up with a clever set of invariants to replace my hand-waving.

Comment: @Steve I don't know if it's ever possible to implement this way, but +1 for inspirational work!

Comment: @Nikita: Thanks, I've certainly reached the point where I either have to define everything formally, or else go to someone with a CS degree (or otherwise expertise beyond the bog-standard structures) and ask them whether they know of something similar...